# Force Chrome/Firefox into Full Screen?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I want to use chrome to display a full-screen html page for a presentation.  You can set chrome to fullscreen mode, but it seems the only way to exit is moving the mouse to the top of the screen and clicking:

[image]

I don't want to disable the ability to exit full-screen, I just want to make it so the only way to exit is via pressing the ESC key, not the mouse position.  That way basically browser "admin" are the only ones who can get out of the presentation.  Is that possible in Firefox or Chrome?  Could I write an extension for this if it's not possible?

Comment: I do hope it's ***not*** possible. I don't want web-sites to be able to emulate, or prevent my access to, my desktop by preventing me from reducing the screen-size of my browser.

Comment: i agree, i just need it to work like flash, where escape is what gets you out, not the mouse position. can firefox do this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible from within the web site, but it should/might be possible to write an extension.

Comment: what about: `chrome.exe -kiosk file:///your/presentation.html`  ?

Comment: jnpcl, how would you run chrome.exe --kiosk from (in-browser) JS??

Comment: The exit from fullscreen is `F11` key.

Comment: @jnpcl if my keyboard doesn't have the f11 key, will it default back to the "Exit fullscreen" dropdown? (it looks like that is happening now, changing keyboards).  can I change f11 to esc?

Comment: @jnpcl: oops, just had to quit chrome.  thank you so much, works perfectly!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Using my comment for an Answer:**

Chrome implemented 'Kiosk Mode' in version 4.0.245.0. This is, essentially, a way to launch the browser in fullscreen mode with the Address Bar and Status Bar disabled. Some keyboard shortcuts (Fullscreen, for example) are also disabled.

On Windows: `chrome.exe -kiosk http://yoursite.com/file.html`

On everything else: `chromium-browser --kiosk http://yoursite.com/file.html`

**Note:** Use your 'exit program' keyboard combo to kill it.

Comment: But it does not take 2 screen? I tried in my Fedora. It takes 1 screen and other screens remain open, how do you apply to all screen?

Comment: Never mind, found it thats all they got: http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc

Comment: on mac os you need to do `open -a "Google Chrome" --args --kiosk http://www.w3.org` and CMD+Q to close it

Answer (score 2):

For firefox, the add-on R-kiosk doea a similar job:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/

I have used it before and it used to be pretty good for kiosk type applications. Haven't needed it in a while though.

To exit, you need to start firefox in safe mode and disable the add-on, which works very well for kiosk purposes.

Comment: Nasty! When I run the above code from Windows Terminal, Chrome disables F11 and the only way to get out of Pres mode is to close the browser. I reported the issue.