# Hide / Show Mobile Browser Nav/URL bar on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, browser

When i scroll down, navigation(url bar) on the phone is automatically hidden.
While when we scroll up, the url bar shows up.

I want that my url bar should still remain hidden even on scrolling up.

Can this be done ?
I have read many blogs and it was mentioned, its not possible using jquery ?

Pleas help

Comment: You mean a mobile browser?

Comment: (also, jQuery will certainly not help here.)

Comment: yes a mobile browswer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is functionality within the browser application and you can't override it.

There is possible way this might be achieved though, and that is to  put the website into full screen mode. The user does have to instigate this themselves though through the website GUI.

See this post if you want to know how it can be achieved: [Set window to fullscreen (REAL fullscreen; F11 functionality) by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179535/set-window-to-fullscreen-real-fullscreen-f11-functionality-by-javascript/25246044#25246044)

Comment: This functions works good with click... but on scroll  this wont work.

Comment: $(function(){
        var CurrentScroll = 0;
        $(window).scroll(function(event)
        {
toggleFullScreen(document.body); //not working
        });
});

Comment: @JamieBarker interesting answer but i guess you show some demo here

Comment: Security functions in the browsers force it so the user must invoke it themselves willingly. a 'click' function will make it work: e.g. `$('body').click(function() { toggleFullScreen(document.body); });`. As I said in my answer: _"The user does have to instigate this themselves though through the website GUI."_

Comment: @JamieBarker so its impossible to hide url while using scroll

Comment: Well you can make it full screen, and then you can scroll the website to your hearts content without it happening. But no you are correct, it will not work in the exact way in which you would like it to work, but its the best you will get.