# ASP.Net MVC Make navigation bar disappear when in full screen mode

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am not sure if this is even possible but it would be a pretty cool thing to have for a dashboard I am creating using Kendo UI and ASP.Net MVC.

So essentially what I would like to do is when a user hits "F11" to go into full screen mode, I would like my navigation bar to collapse, and then open back up if the user exits full screen mode.

**Navbar**

I am simply including the nav bar so everyone can see how it is currently set up. It is pretty much the default generated for MVC.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!--My nav bar items-->
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am quite the beginner at this so I am not sure where to even start. If it makes it any easier, I really only need to do this on a single page. I have a dashboard screen where I would like to set it on a TV and leave in full screen mode.

Any pointers or help would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `:fullscreen` pseudo class in CSS that could detect fullscreen and apply specific CSS. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen).

Unfortunately, pressing F11 doesn't trigger that class because according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392583/fullscreen-api-not-working-if-triggered-with-f11), there are "2 types of fullscreen";

1. Triggered via F11
2. Triggered via a Script

The fullscreen triggered via a Script is the one that the CSS can detect. So here's what I tried that worked;

First, I added an ID to my navbar so I could reference it on my css. An alternative to this is using classes.

```
<div id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Second, I added this so Site.css, this could be found in `Your Project > Content > Site.css`. In the css, we are reducing the navbar height to 0px whenever the page is in fullscreen.

```
        #myNavbar {
            transition: 0.4s;
        }

        html:fullscreen #myNavbar {
            min-height: 0px !important;
            height: 0px !important;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        html:-moz-full-screen #myNavbar {
            min-height: 0px !important;
            height: 0px !important;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        html:-webkit-full-screen #myNavbar {
            min-height: 0px !important;
            height: 0px !important;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
```

Third I added a button (you could put this anywhere on the page) that would programmatically trigger the fullscreen.

```
<button id="full-screen-toggle" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Go Fullscreen</button>
```

Then I added the script to be called whenever we click the button. Add this to the page where you placed a button.

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        document.getElementById('full-screen-toggle').addEventListener('click', function () {
            var doc = document.documentElement;

            if (doc.requestFullscreen) {
                doc.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (doc.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                doc.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
            } else if (doc.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                doc.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }

            return false;
        }, false);
    </script>    
}
```

After clicking the fullscreen button, the navbar should quickly hide itself with a slide animation.