# Display new window fullscreen on second monitor with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a website application which is going to run some countdowns and etc. I want to be able to start/pause/change my countdowns on the primary screen and show it on the secondary screen.

How do i make a second window appear in fullscreen on the second monitor with javascript and HTML?

Comment: Why not let the user do this themselves by opening up a new tab and moving the window?

Comment: That was surely for making an evenemential stage timer.
You have a window for the techincian where he sets countdown and another for the speaker that is displayed full screen on a monitor at his feet. Some configuration are made such as you can't alway see if the display for the speaker is indeed fullscreen and well displayed. Having had a way to force the full screen would have solved such issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly the browser does not give you this exact level of control but it does allow you to send messages between windows.

So for example you could use the [postMessage](https://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage) API to send data between your main website and a window that you create for the user to put on another tab and set to full screen (F11 or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179535/set-window-to-fullscreen-real-fullscreen-f11-functionality-by-javascript))

It would look something like this

File structure

```
| - index.html
| - timer.html
```

index.html

```
...
<script>
var timerTab = window.open('./timer.html', '_blank');
...
timerTab.postMessage(message)
<script>
...
```

timer.html

```
...
<script>
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

// handle messages from the controlling page
function receiveMessage(event) {
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080") // check that it is coming from your site and not somewhere else...
    return;
  // ...
}
<script>
...
```

Answer (score 3):

adding to Menachem Hornbacher's answer, a few new pieces, that might help with this for anyone in 2023+

---

**for getting screens, Chrome**

https://www.w3.org/TR/window-management/#usage-overview-screen-details

```
window.screen.isExtended == true; // yes, has multiple screens

const screenDetails = (await window.getScreenDetails() ).screens; // array of screens
```

---

**window.moveTo() - WILL NOT WORK CROSS SCREEN BOUNDRY**

... but when using OPEN, passing the screen details needed in options like

https://www.w3.org/TR/window-management/#usage-overview-place-windows-on-a-specific-screen

```
const win = window.open(location, '_blank', `left=${left},top=${top},width=${width},height=${height}`)
```

example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76293940/1644202

---

**elem.requestFullscreen(options)**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen

https://www.w3.org/TR/window-management/#usage-overview-place-fullscreen-content-on-a-specific-screen

```
const screenDetailed = screenDetails[1];
await document.querySelector("#elem").requestFullscreen(options={
    navigationUI: "hide",
    screen: screenDetailed
});
```