# Is there a code for making a button act like an another button on the keyboard?

Tags: javascript

I want a button act like `F11` (keyboard) in Google Chrome and like `F10` in Firefox if the device is desktop only. I mean I want place a shortcut for my user so my user shouldn't press `F11` he can click on the button instead `F11` on the keyboard.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179535/set-window-to-fullscreen-real-fullscreen-f11-functionality-by-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set window to fullscreen (REAL fullscreen; F11 functionality) by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179535/set-window-to-fullscreen-real-fullscreen-f11-functionality-by-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fullscreen api to get this result.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

This allow you to request fullscreen for a given element.

Here is an example from w3schools:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_requestfullscreen.asp

Comment: "Here is an example from w3c:" - W3schools _are not the w3c_. They have no affiliation whatsoever. Don't fall for their misleading brand name.

Comment: @Turnip Sorry I corrected it. Thanks for noticing it