# How to disable closing Firefox 7 tab using ctrl+F4

Tags: security, firefox, browser, firefox-addon, kiosk

I have been browsing around to find a way to disable closing Firefox 7 tab using `ctrl+F4`.
Kind of hard to find an easy way to do it. Lock down browser security will help me using  Firefox as a kiosk during the Linux Day event.

Comment: I don't know if they have it better, but you may also consider [Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085184/force-chrome-firefox-into-full-screen) and [Opera](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/) in kiosk mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curious, I've never known <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is able to close the tab.

I've investigated the case a bit. I've tried disabling it in Keyconfig, but without success. The shortcut is not even listed there. When you try to add other shortcut to  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to override the default behavior, it still closes the tab.

Note that also  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is able to close the tab, but in this case you **can** disable it in Keyconfig.

Seems that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> are handled different way therefore.

About <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, I was able to find the following code:

http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/browser/base/content/tabbrowser.xml.html, #else in line 2437:

```js
#ifdef XP_MACOSX
          ...
#else
          if (aEvent.ctrlKey && !aEvent.shiftKey && !aEvent.metaKey &&
              aEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.DOM_VK_F4 &&
              this.mTabBox.handleCtrlPageUpDown) {
            this.removeCurrentTab({animate: true});
            aEvent.stopPropagation();
            aEvent.preventDefault();
          }
#endif
```

I'm new to Mozilla code base, so I don't know where to search for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> however. But it seems <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is hardcoded at compile time for Windows and Linux and not easily (or at all) configurable.

You can think of reporting a bug to [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org) but I don't know if this would get top-priority treatment.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen the [keyconfig addon](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994)?

Or, more directly kiosk-related: [R-kiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/)

Comment: I am using r-kiosk addon but it did not disable `ctrl+F4` closing tab combination...  
This is reported in the addon web page:  
"Notice that the user can still close Firefox with for example Alt-F4 and get access to your computer. You might want to prevent this with a suitable utility program for your operating system." but I don't know how to set it up.

Answer (score 2):

In your Firefox address bar type  **about:config** and hit enter you will be shown the warning to proceed with care, then look for the properties like

- `browser.tabs.warnOnClose`,
- `browser.tabs.closeButtons`,
- `browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab`.

You need to modify the binary values or change the boolean values from true to false or vice versa. If you don't have such entries, create them with `right-click > New > Boolean`.

PS: Please proceed with care.

Comment: I have no browsertabs* entry, I forgot to mention I am on a Fedora 15 laptop (Linux).

Comment: Spelling error: it is `browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab`. If you don't have it however, `right-click > new > boolean`, set the name to above, and value to `false`. Then like the name says, closing last tab wouldn't close the browser. It will just leave empty tab.

Comment: @jakub.gieryluk Close to a viable solution with the `browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab` trick because it avoids from closing the last tab **but** it leaves me with a blank tab... which for a kiosk station might be event worst. At the moment I set up a cron job which restarts the firefox if someone accidentally or on pourpouse hit a `ctrl+F4`.