# In mac 10.6 and above, How to disable ctrl+fn+f4 in kiosk mode?

Tags: macos, xul, macos-carbon, kiosk

Using SetSystemUIMode in carbon framework, I am able to disable apple menu, dock and disable process switching. But ctrl +fn+f4 is able to break the kiosk mode.

Can some one help me how to block this shortcut as well.

Comment: Similar Question here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855452/how-to-disable-closing-firefox-7-tab-using-ctrlf4>

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I cant use this.