# Force full screen in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am currently working on a private web application that is not going to be released to the public. It is relatively straightforward and will run on Google Chrome.

Does anyone have a solution for forcing the browser to enter `Full Screen Mode` when the DOM is ready? I was thinking to simply simulate the `keypress` of the F11 key, but I don't know if this is possible.

Does anyone have a jQuery solution, other than resizing the window to the available width and hiding the navigation (not an ideal solution).

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do this.  I'm also pretty sure the F-keys don't hive keycodes/trigger key events.

Comment: @BenM: This isn't possible (luckily).

Comment: @PeeHaa: Huh, you're right.  Didn't realize that.

Comment: Thanks for all of your replies. Since it's a local application, I can certainly use the kiosk mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085184/force-chrome-firefox-into-full-screen

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As stated by others this isn't possible for obvious reasons already mentioned.

Although since it is a local site why don't you just create a Chrome shortcut for it in fullscreen:

Create a shortcut to Chrome:

```
"C:\Users\techiecorner\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk http://www.example.com
```

http://www.techiecorner.com/1941/how-to-auto-start-chrome-in-full-screen-mode-f11-everytime/

**UDPATE**

By now (HTML5) there is a proposal for a full screen API. To use this you could do something like:

```
// feature detection
if (typeof document.cancelFullScreen != 'undefined' && document.fullScreenEnabled === true) {
  // mozilla proposal
  element.requestFullScreen();
  document.cancelFullScreen(); 

  // Webkit (works in Safari and Chrome Canary)
  element.webkitRequestFullScreen(); 
  document.webkitCancelFullScreen(); 

  // Firefox (works in nightly)
  element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  document.mozCancelFullScreen(); 

  // W3C Proposal
  element.requestFullscreen();
  document.exitFullscreen();
}
```

For more information see the [official specs](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html).

Comment: Facebook has implemented button on other users profile pages, which allows you to switch to full screen... I can see it working in chrome under windows. The code of the buttom doesnt reveal anything: <a data-hover="tooltip" title="" tooltip-position="below" tooltip-alignh="right" href="#" id="fbPhotoSnowliftFullScreenSwitch" aria-owns="js_0" aria-controls="js_0" aria-haspopup="true"></a>.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely not possible, I would consider this a security threat if it was.

If you have control over the environment, you could accomplish this with AppleScript on Mac. Not sure about Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is possible (not considering browser extensions).

Browsers generally don't allow such kind of access to their window. Actually, modern browsers don't even allow you to change the size of the current window (only if it's a popup).

If it's crucial to your application, you should display a message to the user informing him to press F11 when the [browser is not in fullscreen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863351/checking-if-browser-is-in-fullscreen).

Answer (score 0):

This is a no-can-do since you are trying to manipulate the actual program running on the OS.  You can manipulate anything within the browser window, but not outside.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but this gives you some experimental access to full screen aps.  You can simulate a click event and get it to fire.

https://github.com/martinaglv/jQuery-FullScreen

> A jQuery 1.7 plugin that wraps around the Full Screen API and works around various browser differences. Works in FF 10, Chrome and Safari. It is useful for presenting users with an easier to read version of your web pages, or zooming  and  elements.

Comment: This is a little late, but this gives you some experimental access to full screen aps.  You can simulate a click event and get it to fire.