# Firefox : Force full-screen mode from webpage

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

I am developing a web-based database that needs to be opened through firefox web browser(because of some css3 elements). I want the page to open automatically in full screen mode. I dont want the user of the database to have access to the firefox menu items

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085184/force-chrome-firefox-into-full-screen

Answer (score 1):

**Can't be done** if you just have control of the webpage. Controls in the webpage cannot cause changes in the browser instance itself.

It would be a security issue if that were allowed. You could look into writing a Firefox extension to do that, as they have **more access** to the browser instance itself.

You shouldn't look at trying to hide the firefox menu controls. That seems like a flaw in your problem-solving approach.

Comment: I wonder if there is any script to do the same job as the F11 key.

Comment: One way to do this would be to open a popup window (controls dont show up on this window), of the same size as the user's viewport. But this isnt good practice, also, with a little effort, the user can still access firefox menu items.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at Fullscreen APIs of the browser. If you accept a small request/info to the user in the application it can be done quite easily. You just can't force the user into Fullscreen mode against his will. This is good (for security reasons).

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/